AWS Aurora Deleting "Incompatible-create" state DB
How can i delete "Incompatible-create" state AWS Aurora?
This is my RDS structure

cluster-main
ㄴ reader instance
ㄴ writer instance
   ㄴ replica-cluster (Incompatible-create)
   ㄴ replica-writer-instance  (Incompatible-create)

What i tried:

promote `replica-cluster` to delete 'replica-cluster'
-> cannot delete by 'Incompatible-create'

delete cluster-main
-> cannot delete because writer instance's replica is in 'Incompatible-create' state


What i tried:

promote `replica-cluster` to delete 'replica-cluster'
-> cannot delete by 'Incompatible-create'

delete cluster-main
-> cannot delete because writer instance's replica is in 'Incompatible-create' state


